# How can I see how many citations a patent holder has received on their patents?

Tags: citation

I'm mostly interested in USPTO patents, but I am curious about any other patents as well. I don't want to count myself, and Google Scholar mixes up patent citation with paper citations in their total citation count.

I wondered about that question when looking at https://idiyas.com/distribution/pyramid:

[image]

Comment: Interesting site. I had fun reading the AI generated summary of me.

Comment: @EricS I did the same :) those LLMs have some fun inspiration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/search/patent/structured) can generate independent numbers of patents cited and cited by patents. Just select the inventor and refine by whatever filters you want. This can be done internationally so not limited to the USPTO. You can also create a list of the citing patents.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the same site also has a page dedicated to each inventor, where they show the total number of forward citations for USPTO patents.

Example: https://idiyas.com/inventor/shunpei-yamazaki

[image]

Comment: +1 for answering your own question.